# Syntax error while trying to use paymentwall example

Tags: php

Syntax error while using this code , An example from [paymentwall](https://github.com/paymentwall/paymentwall-php/blob/master/README.md)

```
    $widget = new Paymentwall_Widget(
        ''. $_SESSION['PLR_ACCOUNT']['PLR_ID'] .'', 
        'p10_1', 
        array(
            new Paymentwall_Product(
                'product2',                        
                9.99,                                   
                'USD',                                  
                'Elite 3 months',                      
                Paymentwall_Product::TYPE_SUBSCRIPTION, 
                1,                                      
                Paymentwall_Product::PERIOD_TYPE_MONTH,
                true                                  
            ),
            array(
                'email' => 'user@hostname.com', 
                'history[registration_date]' => 'registered_date_of_user',
                'ps' => 'all'
            )
            echo $widget->getUrl();
        )
}
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting ')'
>   in C:\Users\Arlindi\Desktop\X-Portal - V2.6.8 -
>   FINAL\test-server\root\pages\premium_info.php on line 301

Line 301 is

```
echo $widget->getUrl();
```

How to solve it ?

Comment: When you see a parse error it can often be helpful to look at the statement right _before_ the one that's identified. Is the statement before `echo $widget->getUrl()` properly terminated with a `;`? (Since `echo` is the thing that's unexpected we know that PHP is expecting something else in its place.)

Comment: I tried to read there but nothing! I am newbie and trying everything to fix it

Comment: yes i already added getUrl();

Comment: I'm suggesting that you look at the code _before_ that line. Your indentation makes it hard to read, but I think it starts at `$widget = new Paymentwall_Widget(` and continues all the way to line 300. Does that whole chunk of code look correct?

Comment: You didn't close your `$widget` declaration. Using a good IDE/Editor with syntax checking and highlighting will help you catch a lot of the parse/syntax errors.

Comment: can you suggest me any ide editor free that check syntax ?

Comment: Fixed your code for you, should be fairly obvious the problem now. I suggest you try to keep your code formatted well.

Comment: still not working!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your code context!

When you get ***syntax error*** it means you have typo or your code is somehow wrong
as in [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them) explained when you see syntax error,

> Always look at the **code context**. The syntax mistake often hides in the mentioned or in previous code lines. Compare your code against
> syntax examples from the manual.

In your example you used **echo** in your function argument and after array(...)
It is not right in *php*

`function(array(...)echo something;)` **is not correct syntax in php**

*As you didn't say what you want your code actually do, I don't know what can be your correct code but I guess you should close Paymentwall_Widget() parentheses before echo and put one semicolon after the parentheses before echo line*

Comment: how should i change my code ? I got it from PaymentWall website
as an Php Example they said

Comment: @EskimoCnr Answer edited , read last line of my answer and if it solve your problem, please tell